# How to parse span title with jsoup?

Tags: java, android, dom, jsoup

i am trying to parse the title of this content using JSOUP..

```
<div class="article">
<div class="articleHead review">

    <h1 class="item"><span class="fn">OnLive</span> review</h1>
    <h2 class="subGrey"><span class=""></span>Cloud gaming has arrived in the UK, but can our infrastructure make the most of it?</h2>
```

I want to parse the span class OnLive Review.
and the sub header

ive tried this so far..

```
 try{
                     Elements titleElements = jsDoc.getElementsByTag("div");
                         for(Element TitleElement : titleElements){
                             if(TitleElement.attr("class").equals("articleHeader review")){
                                 Element articleHeader = jsDoc.select("#item").first();
                                    String header = articleHeader.text();


                                        System.out.println(TitleElement.text());

                                       title = header.toString();
                                        Log.e("TITLE", title);

                                     }

                    }


                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Couldnt get content");
                    }
```

No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
Element header = jsDoc.select("h1.item span.fn");
Element sub = jsDoc.select("h2.subGrey span");
```